# Airflow container can't connect with a Java API running in localhost

Tags: docker, airflow

I have a simple PythonOperater running inside an Airflow Docker container:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
import requests

api_url = "http://airflow-webserver:5000/fetchHistoricalData/AAPL"
request_headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"}
query_params = None

# Define default_args dictionary to specify the DAG's default parameters
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Vikram Mandal',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Define the DAG
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='api_historical_data_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A DAG to trigger API GET request daily at 1 AM',
    schedule_interval='0 1 * * *', # Schedule to run every day at 1 AM
    catchup=False
)

def send_get_request(url, params=None, headers=None):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an HTTPError for bad responses

        print("GET request successful!")
        print("Response:")
        print(response.text)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"GET request failed: {e}")

def execute_api_call():
    send_get_request(api_url, params=query_params, headers=request_headers)


api_call_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_historical_index_data',
    python_callable=execute_api_call,
    dag=dag,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

When I trigger this DAG, I see below error:

```
[2023-12-06T07:20:33.148+0000] {logging_mixin.py:154} INFO - GET request failed: HTTPConnectionPool(host='***-webserver', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /fetchHistoricalData/AAPL (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9ba20d4730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

My container specs:

```yaml
airflow-webserver:
  <<: *airflow-common
  command: webserver
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  healthcheck:
    test: [ "CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health" ]
    interval: 30s
    timeout: 10s
    retries: 5
    start_period: 30s
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
    airflow-init:
      condition: service_completed_successfully
```

I have a Java API running on localhost: http://localhost:5000.

Can someone explain what is going wrong, do I need to add some options in the Docker container to communicate to the external localhost network?

I have tried setting different operators, but it didn't work. I also checked to see to trigger this API directly thought python script, it works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)